# Install Hyperion.ng - Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB RAM) on Buster (Rev. 2020-02-13)

Tags: linux, ssl, cmake, hyperion, raspberry-pi4

First of all, I have limited knowledge of Linux.

I have tried to install hyperion.ng now on latest Raspian (Buster Rev. 2020-02-13) on a RPi4 (4GB RAM) and ended up in the same scenario all the time.

What I can read it's something wrong with SSL & CMake.

I have run the commands:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essentialqtbase5-dev libqt5serialport5-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev python3-dev libxrender-dev libavahi-core-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libjpeg-dev libqt5sql5-sqlite
3. sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev
4. wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperion-project/hyperion.ng/master/bin/compile.sh | sh

At 100% it's as follow:

```
> [100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/hyperiond
> -- CMake Version: 3.13.4
> CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:18 (CMAKE_POLICY):
>   The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
>   of CMake.
> 
>   The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
>   policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
>   specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
>   behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
> 
> 
> -- PLATFORM is not defined, evaluated platform: rpi
> -- PLATFORM: rpi
> -- ENABLE_AMLOGIC = OFF
> -- ENABLE_DISPMANX = ON
> -- ENABLE_FB = ON
> -- ENABLE_OSX = OFF
> -- ENABLE_SPIDEV   = ON
> -- ENABLE_TINKERFORGE = ON
> -- ENABLE_V4L2 = ON
> -- ENABLE_WS281XPWM = ON
> -- ENABLE_USB_HID = ON
> -- ENABLE_X11 = OFF
> -- ENABLE_QT = ON
> -- ENABLE_TESTS = OFF
> -- ENABLE_PROFILER = OFF
> -- validate json files
>    checked files: 78 success: 78 errors: 0
> -- validate json effect files
>    checked effect files: 38 success: 38 errors: 0
> -- validate json file
> -- Current Version: 2.0.0-alpha.1
> --  - Build: master (GitHub-00502890/2e15ef7c-1581970640) Git Remote: https://github.com/hyperion-project/hyperion.ng.git
> -- Linker: GNU gold
> -- Found Qt Version: 5.11.3
> -- Found libusb-1.0:
> --  - Includes: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
> --  - Libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
> -- Using JPEG library: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so
> -- Using flatbuffers compiler: /home/pi/hyperion/build/bin/flatc
> CMake Deprecation Warning at dependencies/external/protobuf/src/CMakeLists.txt:329 (cmake_policy):
>   The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
>   of CMake.
> 
>   The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
>   policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
>   specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
>   behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
> 
> 
> -- Using protobuf compiler: /home/pi/hyperion/build/bin/protoc
> -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7m.so (found suitable version "3.7.3", minimum required is "3.5")
> -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7m.so (found suitable version "3.7.3", minimum required is "3.4")
> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
>   Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
>   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
>   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.0.0")
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:412 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>   src/hyperiond/CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)
>   src/hyperiond/CMakeLists.txt:260 (InstallDependencies)
> 
> 
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/home/pi/hyperion/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "/home/pi/hyperion/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> make[2]: *** [src/hyperiond/CMakeFiles/hyperiond.dir/build.make:191: bin/hyperiond] Error 1
> make[2]: *** Deleting file 'bin/hyperiond'
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2991: src/hyperiond/CMakeFiles/hyperiond.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you install OpenSSL? `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As squareskittles wrote the libssl was missing.